# Viewport size px?

Tags: html, css, margin, viewport

i'm working on a page site but i have a problem with the viewport between different device. I use the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" >` and the following CSS class for the page.

```
@media only screen {
  html{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
}
```

Body rules contain background-attachment and size, other classes are set as width, height and margins in px. I want to fix them for no display difference in the viewport.

Am i missing some parameter as (max-width) in the @media?

Do i need to set other classe or propertys for the body background(image is very large)?

I'm not using % size or auto-margin so how can i solve the issue?

Comment: What do you mean with `no display difference`? Do you want to scale the background image according to the screen size? I assume you want to add some [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples)

Comment: This could be a solution, the page viewport on PC screen works fine(with vertical scrollbar), but on device(smartphone and tablet) page became too much biggher (i can t upload the image because size is biggher) so i have my element on top and smaller then(even if they have a set width on 1024px or margin)

Comment: What exactly got bigger? Your background image? The div? Did you size the background? Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? You can use [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) to grab an image matching the size you currently use

Comment: You got it. Background size is set to cover and position to center center but image is 2350px for  1262px